# Does Azure Service principle support MFA

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have question related to Service Principle. Can we enabled multi - factor authentication for Service Principle. Can any one confirm me on this.

Also my second question is".    How do MSIs differ from Service Principals in AAD?"

Thanks

Comment: 1. AFAIK, I don't think service principal support MFA. 2. They should be the same, if you enable the MSI of the azure resource, it will create the service principal automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can we enabled multi - factor authentication for Service Principle.
>   Can any one confirm me on this.

In AAD, MFA is for user principals(users), NOT service principals.  I believe that you may mean if we can enable MFA for client_credentials flow in AAD. It's not possible currently.

> Also my second question is". How do MSIs differ from Service
>   Principals in AAD?"

MSI actually uses service principal in AAD. Azure registered a service principal to represent the Azure resource(it's a system managed service). However, this service principal is system managed. Therefore, you can use it but cannot configure it.